# Some simple question of the base change of the unitary group to general linear group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of number fields and $\chi$ is a unitary automorphic character of $E^{\times}$.

Let $\pi$ be an automorphic representation of $U(n)(F)$ associated to $E/F$, which has a base change $BC(\pi)$ to $GL_n(E)$.

Then what is the automorphic representation of $U(n)(F)$ whose base change to $GL_n(E)$ is equals to $BC(\pi)\otimes (\chi\circ \det)$?

I suppose it should be $\pi \otimes \chi_1^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $\chi_1$ is the restriction of $\chi$ to $E^1=\{x\in E \ | \ Norm(x)=1\}$.

Is this right? Because $BC(\chi)(x)=\chi(\frac{x}{\bar{x}})$ for $x\in E$.

If there is some wrong, any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but $\chi_1^{1/2}$ doesn't seem like it needs to be well defined.

Comment: @LSpice, Oh, I am sorry. I mean by $\chi_1^{\frac{1}{2}}$ any character of $E^1$ whose square is $\chi_1$.

Comment: There can be many of those, or none.

Comment: @LSpice, That’s true. Then how about when $\chi$ is trivial on Norm$(E^{\times})$

Comment: I don't know; sorry.